# Problems with LSTM model

Tags: python, python-3.x, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I try to realise LSTM model in PyTorch and got such problem: loss don't reduce. 
My task is so: I have sessions with different features. Session length is fixed and equals to 20. My goal is to predict will the last session been skipped or not. 
I tried to scale input features, I tried to pass `target` into features(maybe provided features are absolutely uninformative, I thought this should lead to overfitting and loss should be near 0), but always my loss reduction looks like this:
[image]

```
print(X.shape)
#(82770, 20, 31) where 82770 is count of sessions, 20 is seq_len, 31 is count of features
print(y.shape)
#(82770, 20)
```

I defined also `get_batches` function. And yes, I know about problems with last batch in this generator

```
def get_batches(X, y, batch_size):
'''Create a generator that returns batches of size
   batch_size x seq_length from arr.
'''
assert X.shape[0] == y.shape[0]
assert X.shape[1] == y.shape[1]
assert len(X.shape) == 3
assert len(y.shape) == 2

seq_len = X.shape[1]
n_batches = X.shape[0]//seq_len

for batch_number in range(n_batches):
    #print(batch_number*batch_size, )
    batch_x = X[batch_number*batch_size:(batch_number+1)*batch_size, :, :]
    batch_y = y[batch_number*batch_size:(batch_number+1)*batch_size, :]
    if batch_x.shape[0] == batch_size:
        yield batch_x, batch_y
    else:
        print('batch_x shape: {}'.format(batch_x.shape))
        break
```

Here is my RNN

```
class BaseRNN(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, n_features, hidden_size, n_layers, drop_p=0.3, lr=0.001, last_items=10):
    super(BaseRNN, self).__init__()
    # constants
    self.n_features = n_features
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.n_layers = n_layers 
    self.drop_p = drop_p
    self.lr = lr
    self.last_items = last_items

    # layers
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
        n_features, n_hidden, n_layers, 
        dropout=drop_p, batch_first=True
    )
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(self.drop_p)
    self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
    self.sigm = nn.Sigmoid()

def forward(self, x, hidden):
    out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
    batch_size = x.shape[0]
    out = self.dropout(out)
    out = out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_size)
    out = self.linear_layer(out)
    out = self.sigm(out)
    # use only last elements
    out = out.view(batch_size, -1)
    out = out[:, -1] 
    return out, hidden

def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    #initialize with zeros
    weight = next(self.parameters()).data
    hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).zero_(),
                  weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).zero_())

    return hidden
```

Here is my train function:

```
def train(net, X, y,
      n_epochs=10, batch_size=10, clip=5):
'''
pass
'''
n_features = X.shape[2]
seq_len = X.shape[1]
net.train()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=net.lr)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
counter = 0
losses = []
for e in range(n_epochs):
    h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
    for x, y in get_batches(X=X, y=y, batch_size=batch_size):
        counter += 1
        h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
        inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(x).float(), torch.from_numpy(y.astype(int))
        targets = targets[:,-net.last_items:].float().view(net.last_items*batch_size)
        h = tuple([each.data for each in h])
        net.zero_grad()
        output, h = net(inputs, h)
        loss = criterion(output.view(net.last_items*batch_size), targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
        opt.step()
return losses
```

Run training:

```
n_hidden = 100
n_layers = 1
n_features = X.shape[2]
net = BaseRNN(n_features, n_hidden, n_layers, 
              lr=0.01, drop_p=0.1, last_items=1)

losses = train(net, X, y, n_epochs=5, batch_size=1000, lr=0.001, clip=5)
plt.plot(losses)
```

After all these steps I get plot like in the top of my question. I think I get a huge error somewhere because I put target variable in features, but still no loss reduction. 
Where I am wrong?

PS.How to generate sample data? I will use real `y` data and add some noise.

```
Y = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
print(Y.shape)
#(10, 20)

# add 5 features with random noise 
random_noise = np.random.randn(10*20*5).reshape(10,20,5)
X = np.concatenate((Y.reshape(10,20,1), random_noise), axis=2)
print(X.shape)
#(10, 20, 6)
```

Comment: One tip to check if your neural net code is correct is first to run the iterations on a  small subset of the entire dataset. If everything is written well, it should overfit within a few epochs. Then you could gradually increase the dataset size and see if your network can converge really. This is a very handy way to troubleshoot neural net code when things don't work well.

Comment: Of course I tried to train on small dataset and my nn still doesn't work properly (no loss reduction even if I add target variable in train set). That is my main question, where I am wrong in code above

Comment: If this is a binary classification problem, why the shape of y is (82770, 20)? It should be (82770,). Can you share sample X and y?

Comment: @ErnestSKirubakaran 20 is sequence length, I tried also many-to-many architecture. I control this via BaseRNN.last_items parameter, setting it to 1 should lead to many-to-one architecture. Nevertheless, I added, how to generate sample data

Comment: One way would be to reduce the learning rate and check for performance improvement as it might be underfitting, personally, I think that the learning rate of 0.01 is too high. Try 0.001 or 0.0003, see if the model improves.

Comment: sorry guys, my fail. I forgot to scale my input variables. Now everything works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fail, forgot to scale input features, now works fine.